# How to use goto after an if statement in batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, goto

I'm sure this question has been asked, or it's obvious, but I can't seem to find the answer! I am making a sort of idle clicker game in batch, and am stuck on going to the upgrades page. The idea is that I want the player to press enter to earn money, and type "upg" to go to the upgrades page. I get an error that says the goto command was not recognized at this time. Then the script closes. Here's what I have:

```
@echo off
title HackerClicker 1.2.1
color 0a
:start
set /a mon = 0 
echo HkrAssociation Hack protocal v. 1.2.1
echo 2015 HkrAssociation. All rights reserved.
echo.
echo press and hold enter in hack routine to auto-hack and gain money
echo.
set /p= "PRESS ANY KEY TO START ROUTINE"
goto routine

:routine
cls
echo Hack Routine v. 1.2.1
echo. 
echo Balance: $%mon%
echo.
echo Type "upg" to go to upgrades
echo.
set /p cmd= "C:\users\h@ck3r\hack_routine>"
set /a mon = %mon% + 1
if %cmd%= upg GOTO upgrades
goto routine

:upgrades
echo more here later
set /p=
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In batch, one equal sign is used for assignment, and two equal signs are used for comparison.  Accordingly, you need to use two equal signs to see if %cmd% is "upg":

```
if %cmd%==upg GOTO upgrades
```

Comment: This works for getting to the upgrades, but when i just press enter to add to money, it just closes the batch script. Is there a way to fix this? Thank you!!!!

Comment: There is nothing in `:routine` that will allow user input.  All you have there is `cls`, `echo`, and `set` commands, until it gets to the `if` statement.  This is a whole different issue than the question as posted.  I provided a solution for the question as it was asked, and you need to post another question about how to get user input in a batch script (after you research it, because this has been asked a gazillion times and you aren't trying to do anything different than the 50 million programmers that came before you).

Comment: Okay, im sorry. Thanks anyway. Your answer helped a lot.

Comment: No need to apologize--just trying to help--the user input thing is too much to address in comments and there's nothing new that I can write about it that hasn't already been written.